# looping over objects in an array inside an object (with for...in)

Tags: javascript

I have objects (people) inside an array (group) inside an object (data) like so:

```
const data = {
  g1 : [
    {"name" : "Jack", "age" : 32},
    {"name" : "Jill", "age" : 44}    
  ],
  g2 : [
    {"email" : "jane@example.com", "city" : "Berlin", "age" : 14},
    {"email" : "brad@example.com", "city" : "Stockholm", "age" : 22}
  ]
}
```

Say I want to `console.log` all age property values, I try:

```
for (const group in data) {
  for (const person of group) {
    console.log(person.age)
  }
}
```

This does not work. It seems `for (const group in data)` is only looping over the names of it's children. I assume I should not use `for...in` in this case, but what can I use? Or is it somehow possible to use `for...in`?

The reason I'm confused is because in for example PHP I could do:

```
<?php

$data = [
    "g1" => [
        [ "name" => "Jack", "age" => 32 ],
        [ "name" => "Jill", "age" => 44 ]
    ],
    "g2" => [
        [ "email" => "jane@example.com", "city" => "Berlin", "age" => 14 ],
        [ "email" => "brad@example.com", "city" => "Stockholm", "age" => 22 ]
    ]
];


foreach ( $data as $group ) {
    foreach ( $group as $person ) {
        echo $person[ 'age' ];
    }
}
```

and in would work.

Comment: You'd need `const person of data[group]` since `group` is the key. Another way is to use `Object.values(data).forEach(group => group.forEach(person => console.log(person.age)));`

Comment: Since you found out that the outer loop gets you `"g1"` and `"g2"`, this is basically a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for...in` construct will provide you only with the keys of an object, not its values. In your outer loop:

```
for (const group in data) { ... }
```

... the variable `group` will be set to `g1`, then `g2`, *not* to the value of the group. To get the value (i.e., the person), you need to index the group:

```
for (const group in data) {
  for (const person of data[group]) {
    console.log(person.age)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One easier way is:

```js
const data = {
  g1: [{
      "name": "Jack",
      "age": 32
    },
    {
      "name": "Jill",
      "age": 44
    }
  ],
  g2: [{
      "email": "jane@example.com",
      "city": "Berlin",
      "age": 14
    },
    {
      "email": "brad@example.com",
      "city": "Stockholm",
      "age": 22
    }
  ]
};

console.log(Object.values(data).map(p => p.map(o => o.age)).flat());
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a much easier way:

```js
const data = {
  g1 : [
    {"name" : "Jack", "age" : 32},
    {"name" : "Jill", "age" : 44}    
  ],
  g2 : [
    {"email" : "jane@example.com", "city" : "Berlin", "age" : 14},
    {"email" : "brad@example.com", "city" : "Stockholm", "age" : 22}
  ]
}

Object.values(data).forEach(group=>group.forEach(person=>console.log(person.age)));
```

Here's another version:

```js
const data = {
  g1 : [
    {"name" : "Jack", "age" : 32},
    {"name" : "Jill", "age" : 44}    
  ],
  g2 : [
    {"email" : "jane@example.com", "city" : "Berlin", "age" : 14},
    {"email" : "brad@example.com", "city" : "Stockholm", "age" : 22}
  ]
}

Object.entries(data).forEach(
  group=>group[1].forEach(
    person=>console.log(
        group[0], 
        person.name ? person.name : person.email, 
        person.age)
  )
);
```

Object.entries return the list of properties and values in an object in an array, i.e., [[prop, val], [prop, val], ...].

So if you use forEach in it, the 0 index will be prop name, and 1 index will be value. This explains the

```
    Object.entries(data).forEach(
      group=>group[1]
```

part. So now we have the group name, and the val which is an array of persons. Then you can just iterate it with another forEach and get age property:

```
   [...]group[1].forEach(
           person=>console.log(person.age));
```

I just elaborated it a bit to get more relevant information with

```
   [...]group[1].forEach(
       person=>console.log(
           group[0], 
           person.name ? person.name : person.email, 
           person.age)
       )
    ) [...]
```

Comment: @ArthurVaïsse Better now ?

Comment: Yep! It is better this way. I still consider the for loop as way more explicit and simpler to tackle this simple problem though. I would only prefer functional style if I were needing some mapping or filtering on the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

many answers here advise using different methods but do not address your issue, or what was missing in your implementation for the ages to be printed.

what you were missing is accessing the values of the `group`, which you iterate.

try this:

```js
for (const group in data) {
  for (const person of data[group]) {
    console.log(person.age)
  }
}
```

which will output

```sh
32
44
14
22
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's try something clean and simple.

```
const data = {
  g1 : [
    {"name" : "Jack", "age" : 32},
    {"name" : "Jill", "age" : 44}    
  ],
  g2 : [
    {"email" : "jane@example.com", "city" : "Berlin", "age" : 14},
    {"email" : "brad@example.com", "city" : "Stockholm", "age" : 22}
  ]
}

consoleAllAges = obj => {
    for (i in obj) {
        const group = obj[i];
        group.forEach(person => {
            console.log(person.age);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

group is an An Array and not An Object. Instead try this

```
    for (const group in data) {
  for (const person of data[group]) {
    console.log(person.age)
  }
}  ​
```

Comment: there is no need for string interpolation

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.values(data)` to return the two arrays g1 and g2 in one array. Then you want to use `flat()` for this array which will give you a single array with all the people inside. Finally you want to call `map()` to iterate over this array. Since `p.age` is implicitly returned to `map()` it will return an array with all the returned values.

```
console.log(Object.values(data).flat().map(p=>p.age));
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings correction

```
  g1 : [
    {"name" : "Jack", "age" : 32},
    {"name" : "Jill", "age" : 44}    
  ],
 g2 : [
    {"email" : "jane@example.com", "city" : "Berlin", "age" : 14},
    {"email" : "brad@example.com", "city" : "Stockholm", "age" : 22}
  ]
}

change string inside
```